# Simplying conditional operators python

Tags: python

I am brand new to programming. Is there any way to simplify the conditional operators

```
a = 50; b = 70; c = 60; 

# Classification 

if (a == b and b == c and c ==a):
   print('Equilateral triangle')

elif (a == b or b == c or c == a):
   print('Isosceles triangle')

elif (a!=b and b!=c and c!=a):
   print('Scalene triangle')
```

Comment: `if a == b == c`

Comment: As a side note, you might consider including inequalities for the case when a b and c do not make a triangle at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can shorten the comparisons that use `and` by using [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), and by dropping one of the tests (they are mutually exclusive), using `else` instead:

```
if a == b == c:
   print('Equilateral triangle')

elif a != b != c != a:
   print('Scalene triangle')

else:
   print('Isosceles triangle')
```

Note that Python's `if` syntax doesn't require any parentheses around the test expressions.

Next, you could look at these values as a *set*, and test how many elements are in the set:

```
unique_lengths = len({a, b, c})

if unique_lengths == 1:
   print('Equilateral triangle')

elif unique_lengths == 2:
   print('Isosceles triangle')

else:
   print('Scalene triangle')
```

This can then be turned into list lookup, mapping `1`, `2` and `3` to triangle class names; I slotted `None` into the `0` position:

```
classes = [None, 'Equilateral', 'Isosceles', 'Scalene']
print(classes[len({a, b, c})], 'triangle')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Out lecturer encourages us to use parentheses. We haven't learned about the set yet.

Comment: @BiLAL: Then your lecturer is going against the [industry standard Python styleguide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but best stick to the conventions they set for now. :-) You'll come across sets soon enough, they can only contain unique elements (as tested by equality), and allow for fast membership testing (*does this set contain this specific value?*), among other handy operations. Turning `a, b, c` into a set when there are shared values among those 3 variables means you'll have a set with fewer than 3 values in it, and we can exploit that to count how many sides are equal.

Comment: Thank you Martijin. I went through the styleguide and it was very helpful. Also i have started learning about sets on youtube. :)

Comment: Is there any document where i can refer to and find a list of all the possible comparisons for different scenarios?

Comment: @BiLAL: not sure what you mean, but that sounds like a very broad question. The reference documentation for comparisons I already linked to, and the [documentation for standard types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) cover any type specific operations.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list:

```py
lis = [a,b,c]
lis.sort()
if lis[0] == lis[-1]:
    print("Equilateral triangle")
elif lis[0] == lis[1] or lis[-1] == lis[1]:
    print("Isosceles triangle")
else:
    print("Scalene triangle")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  But i have not learned about list yet.

Comment: That's ok . But after some months, you will find that codes from Martijn is so clear and ingenious.